# how to make odoo computed relation field caculate itself while importing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, odoo, python-import

i'am added four fields in a view start,end,ignore and range 
range field is computed from start and end field and sometimes using ignore to pop up a record 
the method is working well but while importing data into a mode from excel sheet  range field isn't computed 
this the whole code​

```
class relate(models.Model):
_name = 'relate'
_rec_name = 'car'

@api.multi
@api.onchange('start', 'end', 'ignore')
def years_rang(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.start and rec.end:
            record = [int(x) for x in range(int(rec.start), int(rec.end) + 1)]
            list = []
            if rec.ignore:
                try:
                    record.remove(int(self.ignore))
                    list = []
                except ValueError:
                    return {'warning': {'title': 'Warning!', 'message': "the Ignored year doesn't in range"}}
            for item in record:
                range_id = self.env['yearrange'].create({'name': str(item)})
                list.append(range_id.id)
            rec.rang = [(4, x, None) for x in list]
        pass
start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
rang = fields.One2many(comodel_name="yearrange", inverse_name="product_id",store=True, string="Years" ,)
ignore = fields.Char(string="Ignore", required=False, ) 


class yearrange(models.Model):
    _name = 'yearrange'
    _rec_name = 'name'
name = fields.Char()
product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="relate")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your field `rang` is not computed, because you never told it to be. Just add `compute` parameter on field definition:

```py
rang = fields.One2many(
    comodel_name="yearrange", inverse_name="product_id",
    compute="years_rang", store=True, string="Years" ,)
```

And you should use `api.depends` on the computation method instead of `api.onchange`:

```py
@api.multi
@api.depends('start', 'end', 'ignore')
def years_rang(self):
    # ...
```

On client side you will see, that `api.depends` will have the same outcome like `api.onchange`.

Comment: thank you very much for your  interest , but when i add a compute to the field and depends i get error 
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: That's a problem with the method itself.

Comment: what is solution of it

Comment: @MohamedFouad you should accept this answer, your error is really wired I don't see why you have this error?